# Android GcmNetworkManager PeriodicTask - setRequiredNetwork behavior

Tags: android, gcm-network-manager

I have an Android app which implements `GcmNetworkManager` to schedule a `PeriodTask`.

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/PeriodicTask.Builder#setRequiredNetwork(int)) for `PeriodTask`, it says the following about the behavior of `setRequiredNetwork()`:

> Set the network state your task requires to run. **If the specified network is unavailable your task will not be executed until it becomes available**.

So my question is, does the task fire *immediately* when network becomes available? Or at the next `setPeriod()` interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question, but the task fires immediately.